# Replace submit button with a loading image using jQuery in a WordPress template

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am building a WordPress template and have created a contact form, I want the submit button to be replaced with a loading GIF image on click. Previously on a static html I used the jquery code below to do it.

```
/* ==============================================
Contact Form
=============================================== */
$('form[name="contact-form"]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("div.submit").html('<img class="loading" src="assets/images/loading-infinity.GIF" alt="" />');    

    /* 
        more code goes here 
    */

});
```

To insert images on the template I use `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/myimage.jpg" alt="">`: I use this on template parts of course. So I thought my jquery would look something like this:

```
/* ==============================================
Contact Form
=============================================== */
$('form[name="contact-form"]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("div.submit").html('<img src="<?php bloginfo(&quot;template_url&quot;); ?>/images/loading-infinity.GIF" alt="" />');  

    /* 
        more code goes here 
    */

});
```

However the path to the loading image is still broken? How can I fix the path to the image?

Comment: do you know how to escape strings lol :))

Comment: You could render both the button and image at the same time, with the image hidden then simply `.toggle()` them both (or `.show()`/`.hide()`)

Comment: I don't know about php - does the server parse external .js files (and is your code in a .js file?)  In which case it might not be being parsed.

Comment: You can ask `wordpress` question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
  var src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/loading-infinity.gif"
  $("div.submit").html('<img src="'+src+'" alt="" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

You got broken link because you have used `&quot;` in your code. Try below code instead of `bloginfo()`:

```
 $('form[name="contact-form"]').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("div.submit").html('<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/loading-infinity.GIF" alt="" />');  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
     $('form[name="contact-form"]').submit(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

    $("div.submit").html('<img src="<?php echo bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/loading-infinity.gif" alt="" />');

});
```